# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith') Type Error In Node Js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, mern

I am a New Learner I am Facing This Issue in MiddleWare Everything Is Working Fine before but after I request then this Error will come I am Just Trying To console Log The Token Given In The Header or Applying Condition on Token

This Is The Exact Error ->

```
(node:14020) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useNewUrlParser is a deprecated option: useNewUrlParser has no effect since 
Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14020) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useUnifiedTopology is a deprecated option: useUnifiedTopology has no effect 
since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version
listening on port: 4000
Connected to MongoDB Server

F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\middlewares\requireUser.js:3
    if(!req.headers || !req.headers.authorization || !req.header.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')){
                                                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
    at module.exports (F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\middlewares\requireUser.js:3:80)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)   
    at next (F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (F:\Projects\SOCIAL-MEDIA\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

and My Insomnia Preview Is Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer
This Is code of the MiddleWare File Named requireUser.js

```
module.exports =async(req,res,next)=>{
    if(!req.headers || !req.headers.authorization || !req.header.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')){
        return res.status(401).send("Authorization Is Required");
    }
    let accessToken= req.headers.authorization.split(" ")(1);
    console.log(accessToken);
    next();
}
```

I am Just Trying To console Log The Token Given In The Header or Applying Condition on Token

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the last condition: `header` should be `headers`

```js
if(
    !req.headers || 
    !req.headers.authorization || 
    !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
){
```